# Issues with volumetric fog being too thick

Tags: volumetrics

I tried my best to make a fog scene, but when I added volumetric fog it went just a single color. I can't see any objects, but when I zoom in I can barely see the objects.

Scene:
[image: screenshot 1]

Shader:
[image: shader]

Comment: I guess the *Density* value is too high. What does the shader look like?

Comment: I've tried with a different mode and it has the exact same issue

Comment: [link](https://i.ibb.co/gtXW5Dm/Screenshot-2024-03-23-120024.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***Density* value (1.000) of the *Principled Volume* shader node is too high** so you cannot see through the fog.

If you want a uniformly dense mist effect, you can simply reduce the value. Try `0.1` or even `0.01`. The value depends on the size of your volume cube.

If you want something more like clouds of fog, I recommend using a *Noise Texture* or *Musgrave Texture* node for the *Density* input. For a better clump effect like cloud fog use another *Noise Texture* for the *Vector* input.

[image: cloud fog example]

Finally, use a *Map Range* node to adjust the final density. Experiment with the *From Min* and *From Max* to create holes and clumps. It's similar to a *Color Ramp* node. The *To Min* and *To Max* values define the final density values.

Also try different values for the *Anisotropy* value of the *Principled Volume* node for different density and light effects.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I'm ok without the clouds fog too